# Does the Kotzk dynasty exist today? Is there still a Kotzker rebbe?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, chassidic-rebbe

A while back I was reading about Menachem Mendel Morgensztern Rebbe of Kotzk and found out that the last Kotzker Rebbe in Europe lived in Wyszków my ancestral town. Is there a continuation of the Kotzk dynasty today? Is there a Rebbe? Are there Chasidic who call themselves Kotskers?

Comment: My great-grandmother's grandmother was related to him. I wish I could still see the Kotzk chassidus

Answer (score 4):

The last person to have   gone by the title  "the Kotzker Rebbe" was Rabbi Yitzchak Zelig Morgenstern. He died in 1939 shortly after the Nazis invaded Poland. As a technicality his son Rabbi  Binyamin Paltiel Morgenstern succeeded him but at the time he was a rabbi elsewhere in Poland (in Sokolov) and under Nazi oppression. He and most other children and and virtually all the Hasidim themselves   were murdered in Auschwitz. His grandson  Rabbi  Mendel Meir Morgenstern did survive the holocaust and founded a synagogue in Bnei Brak called Sokolov-Kotzk. That synagogue is still around and about as close a place that considers itself to be a direct contuation of Kotzk around today as there is.

Many Polish based Hasidic groups consider themselves to be offshoots of and based on Kotzk. The current and  previous two Novominsker Rebbes are biologically descendants  of Rabbi Yitzchak Zelig Morgenstern mentioned above (and by extension the Kotzker himself).

Answer (score 1):

Gur and Kotzk were/are closely affiliated, and therefore continues through Gur.

Comment: Yes but they are different dynasties. Gur or Gerer chasids don’t describe themselves as Kotzker Hasidim

Comment: @YehoshuaShalomHaleviSegal They don't, but I've heard it said that the Chidushei Harim's Torah is pure Kotzker Torah.